# mongoose findOne stuck when data not exist

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

### Description

I use `Model.findOne().exec()` according to the mongoose document, there are `{ username: ycjcl666 }` in my mongodb, when I `findOne({ username: 'ycjcl666' })` , it can disply the data, but I query no existed data like `findOne({ username: 'ycjcl888' })` , the application stucked.

### Application

use `koa@2 + mongoose@^5.0.18 + mongodb@3.6.3` to create a login/register application.

controller code:

```
// controller/user.js
class UserController {
  async login(ctx) { 
    const password = await UserService.loginPass(username);
  }
}
```

servcie code, like this, but it stuck when not existed, I `try...catch` but not get `console` info

```
// service/user.js
class UserService {
  async loginPass() {
     return User.findOne({ username }).exec();
  }
 }

// model/user.js
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import timeZone from 'mongoose-timezone';

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const schema = new Schema({
  model: {
    id: String,
    name: String,
  },
  avatar: String,
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    trim: true,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  count: {
    type: Number,
    default: 0,
  },
  updated_at: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
  created_at: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
}, {
  // remove __v
  versionKey: false,
  timestamps: {
    createdAt: 'created_at',
    updatedAt: 'updated_at',
  },
});

schema.index({ username: 1 }, { unique: true });
schema.index({
  updated_at: -1,
});

schema.plugin(timeZone);
export default mongoose.model('User', schema);
```

### Screenshot

[image]

Comment: Try enclosing `const userInfo = await User.findOne({ username }).exec();` within try and catch and check if `User.findOne()` is throwing an error.

Comment: No console error info

Comment: I really don't like seeing code like this. Why are you trying to resolve an async call inside another function? Why can you not simply return the promise and resolve the value there. The result is either something or `null`.

Comment: I think you also just made it worse adding the `try..catch`. Now where `null` it will not return anything.

Comment: @K.King You can revert that back in that case. Just wanted to check if it is throwing an error.

Comment: So what is the answer, eventually?

Answer (score 0):

You are using `await` in `await UserService.loginPass(username);` that mean `loginPass` must return a `Promise`, I mean you do not nead to use `await` in `loginPass` function

```
class UserService {
  loginPass() {
    return User.findOne({ username }).exec();
  }
 }

class UserController {
  async login(ctx) { 
    const password = await UserService.loginPass(username);
  }
}
```

or

```
class UserService {
  async loginPass() {
    return await User.findOne({ username }).exec();
  }
 }

class UserController {
   login(ctx) { 
    const password = UserService.loginPass(username);
  }
}
```

and also make sure you are not using `async/await` where you are calling `UserController.login` (if calling explicitly)

Comment: Maybe, but that was actually just an edit to the code within the last minute. See the original post https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/50409126/1 . There was not even an `if` in there. So the problem is awaiting a promise on a `null` value is what I was getting at in the comments.

Comment: It is still stuck, in `controller/user.js` I code `const hashPass = await UserService.loginPass(username);`.

Comment: @K.King The point is that `await` inside a function is not a good pattern. It's okay if you need to await the value and return something else ( as long as the "else" is a Promise ), but the value you return really should be the `Promise`, and not a resolved value like you seem to think it works.

Comment: why I search the existed data ,it displayed. but not existed, it was `Promise{ <pending> }` all the time.

Comment: @Arif Khan The second, the password got `Promise{ <pending> }`

Comment: So what is the answer, eventually?